# How to create multiple big tables using HVObox in HVFloat

Tags: tables, width, split, hvfloat

I have a several wide tables which I need to split over multiple pages for a book.
The idea being that the left page shows the left half of the table, the right page the right half.

For example something like this

[image]

I found the hvfloat package, which works for 1 table.
But if I make more than 1 table it will simply put multiple copies of the same table (the last one to be stored in the HVObox) in the document.

How do I create multiple tables like this in the same document?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This sounds like either a problem of how you're using the `hvfloat` facility or a bug.  If you create a small compilable example of what's happening and send it to the author of the package, I believe you'll get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That are floating environment, which is the reason why it will only work if you have enough text between these double side tabular (Boxes). If not, it is not possible to place the object in a correct way. A working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hvfloat,booktabs,blindtext}
\renewcommand\thepage{\Huge\arabic{page}}
\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\savebox\hvOBox{%
\begin{tabular}{l*{18}r} \toprule
    & \textbf{1972} & \textbf{1973} & \textbf{1974} & \textbf{1975} & \textbf{1976}& \textbf{1977} & \textbf{1978} & 
    \textbf{1979} & \textbf{1980} & \textbf{1981} & \textbf{1982} & \ textbf{1983} & \textbf{1984} & \textbf{1985}& 
    \textbf{1986} & \textbf{1987} & \textbf{1988} & \textbf{1989} \\\midrule\addlinespace[3pt] 
    Zeile1&1&3&1&1&1&0&1&1&0&0&0&0&20&0&2&2&2&1\\\addlinespace[3pt]
    Zeile2&1&1&3&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&2&1&3&4&4&6&4&2\\\addlinespace[3pt] 
    Zeile3&2&1&2&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&5&3&1&7&7&3\\\addlinespace[3pt]
    Zeile4&1&0&5&1&2&0&0&0&0&2&1&0&1&0&3&7&2&1\\\addlinespace[3pt]
    Zeile6&2&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&2&0&5&2&2&5&4&2\\\addlinespace[3pt]
    Zeile5&0&0&4&2&1&2&2&1&0&0&0&1&1&0&2&5&4&3\\\addlinespace[3pt] 
    Zeile8&0&1&1&0&0&0&1&1&0&3&2&1&2&1&3&5&3&4\\\addlinespace[3pt]
    Zeile9&0&0&0&0&0&1&2&1&0&0&0&0&4&2&1&4&5&2\\\addlinespace[3pt] 
    Zeile10&0&1&3&0&1&0&1&0&0&1&1&0&1&1&1&4&4&1\\\addlinespace[3pt]
    Zeile11&0&2&2&1&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&2&6&1&0&2&1&1\\\addlinespace[3pt] 
    Zeile12&2&0&2&4&1&0&4&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&3\\\addlinespace[3pt]
    Lärm &2&3&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&2&0&0&2&2&2\\\addlinespace[3pt]
    Zeile13&0&1&0&0&1&0&3&0&0&0&0&0&2&0&1&3&0&2\\\addlinespace[3pt]
    Zeile14&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&3&3&2&1&1&0\\\addlinespace[3pt] 
    Zeile15&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&4&0&0&3&1&1\\\addlinespace[3pt]
    Zeile16&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&3&5&0&1\\\addlinespace[3pt]\midrule
    Artikelgesamt&2&6&13&8&4&3&5&4&0&6&3&5&23&10&8&15&13&1\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\hvFloat[doublePage,useOBox,capPos=right,capVPos=top,floatCapSep=12pt]% 
  {table}%
  {}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  [A doublepage tabular with a caption on the right side of the 
   right part.]%
   {A caption for a double-sided tabular that will be placed on the right side of the right-hand part of the illustration.}%
  {tab:doublePage0}

\Blindtext[8]

\savebox\hvOBox{%
\begin{tabular}{l*{18}r} \toprule
        & \textbf{1972} & \textbf{1973} & \textbf{1974} & \textbf{1975} & \textbf{1976}& \textbf{1977} & \textbf{1978} & 
    \textbf{1979} & \textbf{1980} & \textbf{1981} & \textbf{1982} & \ textbf{1983} & \textbf{1984} & \textbf{1985}& 
    \textbf{1986} & \textbf{1987} & \textbf{1988} & \textbf{1989} \\\midrule\addlinespace[3pt] 
    Zeile1&1&3&1&1&1&0&1&1&0&0&0&0&20&0&2&2&2&1\\\addlinespace[3pt]
    Zeile16&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&3&5&0&1\\\addlinespace[3pt]\ midrule
    Artikelgesamt&2&6&13&8&4&3&5&4&0&6&3&5&23&10&8&15&13&1\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\hvFloat[doublePage,useOBox,capPos=right,capVPos=top,floatCapSep=12pt]% 
  {table}%
  {}
  [A doublepage tabular with a caption on the right side of the right part.]%
  {A caption for a double-sided tabular that will be placed on the right side of the right-hand part of the illustration.}%
  {tab:doublePage1}
    
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Change the line `\Blindtext[8]` between the two tabular to `\Blindtext[4]` and it will fail, too less text between the objects.

A workaround is to place *two* tabulars in the box or to use nonfloating environments and placing the objects by hand on the facing pages.

Comment: That explains it, thanks. This is not something behaviour I would've expected so I was completly stuck.